# How to read json data from appsetting.json

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I want to read some data from the appsetting.json file using blazor C#. here is code

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Test1": "Server=KHITGFDB;Database=TESTDB;Trusted_Connection=True;",
    "AuditDatabase": "Server=KHITGGF;Database=TISA;Trusted_Connection=True;",
    "EpriseDatabase": "Server=BHUIL,50397;Database=DUON;User ID=yHISNeBHID;Password=HGTUKHJSAC;"
  },
  "EmailRecipients": "a@test.com;b@test.com:c@test.com"
}
```

I want to read EmailRecipients from appsetting.json to text.razor page. Here is the following code.

Test.razor

```
 public void saveShareFeedback()
    {
        if (feedback.Rating == 0) return;

        feedback.UserId = "Tester";
        feedback.EmailRecipients = "a@test.com;b@test.com:c@test.com";


        var ack = _db.SaveFeedbackData(feedback);
        if (ack == true)
        {
            isSharedFeedback = true;
            msg = "Thanks for sharing your feedback...";
            feedback = new Feedback();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should be using `dependency injection` to inject your `IConfig` created in your `startup.cs` file to the class which needs to use it. Then you can use `IConfig.GetValue<string>("YourKey")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is server side Blazor. Inject the `IConfiguration`. You can use this to get any stored value in the appsettings.json (, if the value is not overwritten from the command line arguments.)

```
string emailRecipients = _configuration["EmailRecipients"];
```

```
public class SomeClass
{
   private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

   public SomneClass(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
       _configuration = configuration;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this quick response and it works perfectly.

Comment: and from any class ? how access to it?

Comment: Utilize the build in Dependency Injection.